R Shiny app connected to BigQuery cannot filter by dates
I'm working on a R Shiny app that used to load the data from a CSV file and display it on a plot. The user had the ability to do some filtering via dropdowns and dateRangeInput selectors.
My goal is to scrap the CSV file and connect directly to BigQuery (which is where the original data table is located). Most importantly, I don't want to download the data from BigQuery into R's memory as it would give no improvement in terms of efficiency. To do so, I have had to do a lot of re-coding for the filtering, transforming code written in base R to dbplyr verbs.
It all seems to work until I get to filtring on the dates. Whenever I add the conditon on the dates, I get an error saying "Error in .transformer: value must be a string or scalar SQL, not the number 1."
This is a minimal example that gives me the error:
library(shiny)
library(dbplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(bigrquery)

choices <- c(1, 2)

bq_conn <- dbConnect(
  bigrquery::bigquery(),
  project = "project_name", 
  dataset = "dataset_name",
  billing ="billing_name"
)

# read the data
df <- tbl(bq_conn, "10_C_app_input_data") %>%
    filter(atc_direction == 1)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 2,
      
      dateRangeInput(inputId = "dates",
                     label = "Period to view",
                     start = "2023-10-01",
                     end = "2024-09-30",
                     min = "2023-10-01",
                     max = "2024-09-30")
    ),
  
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("testplot", 
                   height = "70vh", 
                   width = "80vw")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  visual_filter <- reactive({ 
      df %>% 
        filter(
          & (datefull >= input$dates[1])
          & (datefull <= input$dates[2])       
      )
  })
  

  output$testplot <- renderPlotly({

    full_ggplot <- ggplot(visual_filter()) +
      geom_line(aes(x = datefull,
                    y = flow,
                    linetype = flow_type,
                    color = flow_type)) 
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)



I have tried doing the filtering without a reactive and this seems to show the same behaviour - all works unless I try to filter by dates.
I should also add that I have tried converting both datefull and input$dates[i] to date using as.Date but this has had no effect.

Edit
As per comments, I have removed the direction selector as this works fine. I have also tried the following steps:

replaced the input$dates with actual values in the form of strings (i.e. having something like datefull >= "2023-10-01") and this works fine but of course this is not the desired behaviour
adding lubridate converters to the filtering statement (i.e. like ymd(datefull) >= ymd(input$dates[1])) but again this is throwing the dame error. I have also tried applying ymd or lubridate::as_date directly to the column datefull in a mutate verb when I read the data but I get the same error.

Note that I have also separately printed the content of input$dates into a htmlOutput on the app panel and I can confirm it's dates of the desired format yyyy-mm-dd.

Have you tried out of shiny? - it would help a lot the readers if you keep only the read data + filter steps and replace the inputs by their values.
Also are you sure it's linked to the dates? - error says "the number 1" and it's the default choice for input$direction

You are not able to filter the data by dates likely because the dates in the fetched data frame is not properly formatted. Use Lubridate's as_date() function or ymd() to format the date to be consistent with the yyyy-mm-dd pattern and see if that helps.

Thanks both @thekangaroofactory, I have edited with the outcome of my tests

Assuming that datefull >= "2023-10-01" produces filtering as expected (just not dynamic). Then as Ifeanyi Idiaye commented, this is most likely due to differences in data formats.

It is reasonable to assume dateRangeInput returns variables of type date.
It would be worth checking the data type of the data in BigQuery.


The exact solution depends on the BigQuery data type. Note that you may not be able to judge this just from visual inspection: 2024-12-13 looks a lot like '2024-12-13' but one may be stored as date and the other stored as character.
You can try something like the following to see how R interprets the data type, but this may differ from the BigQuery date type:
df %>%
  select(datefull) %>%
  head() %>%
  collect() %>%
  pull() %>%
  class()


If the datefull is stored in BigQuery as date, then the problem is with dbplyr translation. I would test this using:
df %>% 
  filter(
    (datefull >= input$dates[1])
    & (datefull <= input$dates[2])       
  ) %>%
  show_query()

In the worst case I would simplify filter down to create the minimum translation:
visual_filter <- reactive({ 
  sdate = input$dates[1]
  edate = input$dates[2]

  out = filter(df, datefull >= sdate)
  out = filter(out, datefull <= edate)

  out
})

If the datefull is stored in BigQuery as character in YYYY-MM-DD format, then I would try: datefull >= as.character(input$dates[1]). This means the comparison is occurring in text format, based on alphabetic sorting. Alphabetic sorting of text in the format YYYY-MM-DD is equivalent to numeric sorting.
If the datefull is stored in BigQuery as character in a different format, then you need to figure out a way to change its format. Perhaps something like: sql(CAST(datefull AS DATE)) >= input$dates[1].
If the datefull is stored in BigQuery as numeric - it is probably 'days since a reference date'. You will need to find out what the reference date is. You then have the choice of converting input$dates to 'days since reference date' or converting the datefull to date.

Many thanks for your thorough answer. I think the issue is with dbplyr converting the verbs to a query because I couldn't execute show_query() at all. I also checked the data type and it was Date both in BigQuery and in the table read in R.
So I went on "deconstructing" the filter as you did in your last point and this has worked. Very strange behaviour

You are welcome @Caligula. If I have answered your question, you can accept my answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This gives me some reputation as a reward for my effort and lets other site users know that your question has been answered.
